# j_spring_security_check always redirect to login

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I got spring security 4 with custom login form and custom `UserDetailsService`. The problem is every time i submit to `j_spring_security_check` it will always redirect back to login page. It feels like it's treating `j_spring_security_check` another resource within my container.

below is my config. Anything I'm missing?

**application-security.xml**

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/css/**/*.css" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/fonts/*.*" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/landing" authentication-failure-url="/login?error" authentication-success-handler-ref="loginSuccesHandler" />
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
    <security:csrf disabled="true" />
</security:http>
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider ref="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>
<bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
    <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder" />
</bean>
<bean id="userDetailsService" class="a.b.c.MyAppUserDetailService" />
<bean id="loginSuccesHandler" class="a.b.c.LoginSuccessHandler" />
<bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder" />
```

**login.jsp**

```
<body>
    <form action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check'/>" name="f" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="username">Username</label> <input type="text" name="j_username" id="username" class="form-control" style="font-size: 1.5em" maxlength="100" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="password">Password</label> <input type="password" name="j_password" id="password" class="form-control" style="font-size: 1.5em" maxlength="100" />
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-info btn-block shadow-z-3" type="submit"> Login </button>
    </form>
</body>
```

**login controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/login")
public class LoginController {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(HttpSession session,HttpServletRequest req, ModelMap model) {
    AuthenticationException ase = (AuthenticationException) session.getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION");
    if (ase != null) {
        model.addAttribute("errorMsg",ase.getMessage());
    }
    return "login";
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String logout(HttpSession session) {

    return "login";
}
}
```

Comment: what do the logs say when you attempt to login? is authentication attempt being triggered and successful? it may also help if you post the LoginSuccessHandler.java.

Comment: there is no error logs.. my `MyAppUserDetailService` is not even triggered. to me it seems like it's treating `j_spring_security_check` as a protected resource, whenever i post to it, it will redirects back to login page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer. there is difference in spring 4 vs spring 3. after adding `login-processing-url` attribute to `form-login` it's working as expected.

check out this [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html#m3to4-xmlnamespace-form-login) for details.